# How can I remove a package?

Tags: apt, uninstall

How to remove `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic` from my system?

I can't install any package because of this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 152 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 225623 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic (3.13.0-49.83) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-49-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-49-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_UCk0cv/lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_UCk0cv/lib/modules/3.13.0-49-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Added Linux  *
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's not the same as `http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot` question as `apt-get purge xxx` doesn't work(the same error).

Comment: What is the error message if you try to install a package? Try this command: `sudo apt-get install aptitude` because we need this tool.

Comment: Have you try to run the command? sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched lots of answers and tried every one I can with no luck.

the `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get install otherpackage` all get the same error as above in the end:

I can't install or remove any packages. The solution is simple(It took me one day):

Just download `vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.efi.signed` file to `/boot` folder, then run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Since then everything is ok. Thanks all for you help and time!